session Crashing: while installing python version 3.7 and transformers version 4.6.0 in Google Colab
I am working on a project for Meta Review Generation. I have picked my base paper as "MReD: A Meta-Review Dataset for Structure-Controllable Text Generation", the code and the data are give in the following git link " https://github.com/Shen-Chenhui/MReD " . The model requires python 3.7 and transformers 4.6.0 to run but I am unable to download it on Google colab notebook. I need assistance in solving this issue.
I have tried following commands:
#to install python 3.7
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!python --version

#to install pip
!sudo apt install python3-pip

#to solve distutils missing issue
!sudo apt install python3.7-distutils

#to install transformers 4.6.0
!pip install transformers==4.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

the error that shows after running the above command is -
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. launchpadlib 1.10.16 requires httplib2, which is not installed. lazr-restfulclient 0.14.4 requires httplib2>=0.7.7, which is not installed.
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime:
  [certifi]
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.

As soon as I restart the colab it crashes, and fails to restart again and gets disconnected. Further it shows "unable to connect".
